# PDO query returning False half the time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepare

I have a problem with PDO mysql queries

HEre is my simple code (not a real situation just to show you the problem)

```
$connexion = new PDO(SQL_DSN, SQL_USERNAME, SQL_PASSWORD);
$stmt = $connexion->prepare('SELECT * from missions,platforms WHERE missions_platforms_id = exl_platforms_id AND missions_id = :mission');
$stmt->execute(array(":mission" => '1'));
$ligne = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($stmt);

$stmt = $connexion->prepare('SELECT * from missions,platforms WHERE missions_platforms_id = exl_platforms_id AND missions_id = :mission');
var_dump($stmt);
$stmt = $connexion->prepare('SELECT * from missions,platforms WHERE missions_platforms_id = exl_platforms_id AND missions_id = :mission');
var_dump($stmt);
```

and the output :

```
object(PDOStatement)[2]
 public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * from missions,platforms WHERE missions_platforms_id = platforms_id AND missions_id = :mission' (length=122)

boolean false

object(PDOStatement)[2]
 public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * from missions,platforms WHERE missions_platforms_id = platforms_id AND missions_id = :mission' (length=122)
```

Why the 2nd var_dump return false ?

If I do more times the same schema it is returning false half the time...

Thanks you

Comment: Is there any PHP error printed? Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);` before that code.

Comment: Also try adding a PDO::errorInfo call - see the example here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Thank you Mike !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to close your result set cursor after reading the result set with `PDOStatement::fetch()` using [`PDOStatement::closeCursor()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php) such as:

```
$connexion = new PDO(SQL_DSN, SQL_USERNAME, SQL_PASSWORD);
$stmt = $connexion->prepare('SELECT * from missions,platforms WHERE missions_platforms_id = exl_platforms_id AND missions_id = :mission');
$stmt->execute(array(":mission" => '1'));
$ligne = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($stmt);
$stmt->closeCursor();

$stmt = $connexion->prepare('SELECT * from missions,platforms WHERE missions_platforms_id = exl_platforms_id AND missions_id = :mission');
var_dump($stmt);
$stmt = $connexion->prepare('SELECT * from missions,platforms WHERE missions_platforms_id = exl_platforms_id AND missions_id = :mission');
var_dump($stmt);
```

The first statement is the only statement you actually fetch a result from.